# How to go back to previos view with back button (android)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

This is my main. when clicked the btn, listview activity starts:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);


            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This is my listevents activity. It sets the view of lists, when one of listviews clicked, it shows textview in another view.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mContext = getBaseContext();
        db = new DBHandler(mContext);

        listView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_list, null);
        showView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.show_description, null);


        setContentView(listView);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, events));
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                    desc = (TextView) showView.findViewById(R.id.desc);

                    desc.setText(events.get(position).getDescription());
                    setContentView(showView);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

when after showview (textview) is shown, i clicked back button, instead of going to listview, it goes to main (where i clicked btn to come to listview). I used fragments here:

```
        listView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_list, null);
        showView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.show_description, null);
```

Why doesnot it go?

Comment: Where it is going at the moment is the correct place. If you want to change what the back button does override `onBackPressed` or use `Fragment`s to control the back stack

Comment: lol I thought i used fragments with those     
            listView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_list, null);
            showView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.show_description, null); so, not so easy handling fragments?

Comment: THose aren't fragments.  All you're doing is inflating two separate laypouts.  And really, what you're doing is very wrong.  You should port it to actual fragments.

Comment: Why wrong, they are simple layouts. I dont want to make it bigger with fragments.

Comment: By setContentView(showView); you are just reusing the listevents activity so when you press back button it will certainly navigate back to its previous activity i.e main activity. Either you change it to navigate to new actitivity or intercept onbackpressed and do setContentView(listView); properly again.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

This site explains perfectly. It only took a quick Google search of Android up navigation.

Also for more of what you are looking for. You want to catch the up navigation.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    //switch to list view
}
```

Comment: but they are not activities. only views with textviews

Comment: So, you say i can go on using those seperate layouts instead of actual fragments with those backpressed?

Comment: Sure thing. `setContentView(listView)` with of course making list view the same way you did previously using layoutInflater

Comment: However. @GabeSechan was very smart in what he told you. You CAN do it the way I explained, the PROPER way would be to use Fragments

Comment: and i couldnot where to put those onbackpressed method. It all gives errors not allowed annotation here.

Comment: Well. Where'd you put it?

Comment: I put to listview class but this time when i click before going to showview, it doesnot go to main, it stays in listview. So, fragments seem the way